# a2ensite throwing errors with sudo user

Tags: apache-2.2

I am running as a user with sudo privileges for apachectl and a2ensite. I also have ownership of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled, /etc/apache2/sites-available

WHen I run a2ensite , it creates the symbolic link appropriately, but throws an error:

```
Enabling site xxxxx.
touch: cannot touch '/var/lib/apache2/site/enabled_by_admin/xxxxx': Permission denied
```

Why is a2ensite writing to this directory? I can't find anything in the man about it.

Comment: What's the permissions of the directory?

Comment: It looks like there may have been a problem originating on puppet, and the sudo privileges for the user weren't pushed out. But I'm still curious why a2ensite tried to write to that directory in the first place